# How to use port names in record nodes in pydot

Tags: python, graphviz, dot, graph-visualization, pydot

I haven't been able to find a way to draw nodes with ports in pydot: neither in the documentation nor in examples on the web.

Is there a way to draw the following graph using pydot?

diagram:

```
          +-----------+
          |   | G |   |
          +-----------+
           /         \
          /           \
   +-----------+  +-----------+
   |   | E |   |  |   | R |   |
   +-----------+  +-----------+
```

dot code:

```
digraph g {
 node [shape = record,height=.1];
 node0[label = "<f0> |<f1> G|<f2> "];
 node1[label = "<f0> |<f1> E|<f2> "];
 node2[label = "<f0> |<f1> R|<f2> "];
 "node0":f2 -> "node2":f1;
 "node0":f0 -> "node1":f1;
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding label attributes like this:

```
In [1]: import pydot

In [2]: N = pydot.Dot()

In [3]: N.set_node_defaults(shape='record')

In [4]: p = pydot.Node('node0', label = "<f0> |<f1> G|<f2> ")

In [5]: N.add_node(p)

In [6]: N.write_dot('foo.dot')
```

Comment: Thanks, but could you specify how to create an edge from `node0` port `f0` to `node1` port `f1` in pydot?

Comment: Now i see, if I do `pydot.Edge('node0:f0', 'node1:f1')` it works.